# Permutation function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Can anyone write a function that generates a permutation matrix from zero to a x number in this way? For example:

myfunc(x,y) where x is the max number and y is the number of columns. For example:

myfunc(2,3) and generates this result:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
2 0 0
2 0 1
2 1 0
2 0 1
1 2 0

...
all the way to 222
```

It's for testing p d q values of a ARIMA(p,d,q) model

Comment: Have a look at the matlab file exchange. Resp., search for 'ttoolboxes',  where a similar function 'mixvector' is included.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that x is 9 or less, then you could use a base conversion function as follows:

```
function z = myfunc(x,y)
z = dec2base(0:((x+1)^y-1),x+1) - '0';
end
```

If x could be larger than 9, then more generic code would be required:

```
function z = myfunc(x,y)
z = arrayfun(@(c)base2dec(c,x+1),dec2base(0:((x+1)^y-1),x+1));
end
```

In both cases, note that if the x and y are too large then the conversions will not work and/or you will run out of memory. In either case, the basic strategy is to simply count in base (x+1) from 0 to the total that you want, which is (x+1)^y-1.